# Just cant get the for loop to produce needed array in Php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need my for loop to return an array that looks like this

```
    $nullArray =array(
 0 => array("id" => 1, "label" => "test 1", "type" => "folder"), 
      array("id" => 2, "label" => "test 2", "type" => "folder"),
      array("id" => 3, "label" => "test 3", "type" => "folder"),
      etc...
      etc... 
      etc...
);
```

what I have right now

```
 $nullArray = array();
$numOfVer = mysql_num_rows($result);
$startArray= array();

//SETS FIRST NODE
for($i =0;$i < $numOfVer;$i++)
{
    $label = mysql_result($result, $i);
    $id = $i+1;
    $startArray = array(array('id' => $id,'label' => $label, "type" => "folder"));


    //$startArray[]['id'] = $id;
    //$startArray[]['label'] = $label;
    //$startArray[]['type'] = "folder";
     //array_push($startArray,array(array('id' => $id,'label' => $label, "type" => "folder")));
    //$nullArray[0]= array(array('id' => $id,'label' => $label, "type" => "folder"));
    //array_push($nullArray[0],array('id' => $id,'label' => $label, "type" => "folder"));
}
$nullArray[0] = $startArray;

    echo json_encode($nullArray[0]);
```

Everything that I have commented out is something that I have tried and it has failed. I'v been at it for too long for something so simple so I decided to get some help! Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Specifically, what is not working in the code you have above?

Comment: Try with `$i` like this: `$startArray[$i]['id']` and etc..

Comment: it was solved by guy below! thanks for the effort guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In for loop you are redclaring your $startArray thats why the previous value removed. Try this.

```
$nullArray = array();
$numOfVer = mysql_num_rows($result);
$startArray= array();

for($i =0;$i < $numOfVer;$i++)
{
    $label = mysql_result($result, $i);
    $id = $i+1;
    $startArray[] = array('id' => $id,'label' => $label, "type" => "folder");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm. Its funny how when you stare at a piece of code too long you forget the simplest things .